# Loop ui-select-match with list string

Tags: angularjs

I have a code below, it is getting infinite loop. I don't know what it can be:

```
            <ui-select class="new-car" ng-model="vm.carr.motor.piston" search-enabled="false" required

            ng-disabled="vm.pendencieslist.length && !vm.haveFieldPendencies('CodePiston')"

            data-id="CodePiston"

            ng-change=" vm.googleAnalytcs('motor','piston',vm.car.motor.piston)">

                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select here" class="selected-new-car">{{$select.selected.pistonDescription}}

                </ui-select-match>

                <ui-select-choices repeat="option.valor as option in [{valor:undefined, pistonDescription: 'Select here' }, {valor: true, pistonDescription: vm.car.motor.pistonName}, {valor:false, pistonDescription: 'No activate'}]">

                    <div ng-bind="option.pistonDescription"></div>

                </ui-select-choices>

            </ui-select>
```

Resolve the infinite looping